# Get the text from current text zone

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm developing a .NET app that involves text analyzing.

i would like to retrieve the text from the current focused window active text box. And much preferably from the location of the Windows cursor

This should be independent of the process, meaning if the user is writing in Word i would like to retrieve the words typed "near" the position of the cursor, also in Chrome or IE url etc.

Does anyone knows of a good solution to this in .NET?

Comment: how is this different from a keylogger?

Comment: @ScottSelby Does it really matter?

Comment: @ScottSelby And why would it matter?

Comment: key logger is one implementation i thought about but

Comment: But i want to know about a solution more close to my question. There are some resones why keylogger isnt the ideal approach here

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point would be to get the control that the mouse is over, which can be done like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr ChildWindowFromPoint(IntPtr hWndParent, Point Point);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point Point);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ScreenToClient(IntPtr hWnd, ref Point lpPoint);

//...

Point p = Cursor.Position;
IntPtr phwnd = WindowFromPoint(Cursor.Position);
ScreenToClient(phwnd, ref p);
IntPtr hwnd = ChildWindowFromPoint(phwnd, p);
```

From there you can get the text from the control in a method similar to the one answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740920/1794305