# Using user32.dll to automate some things or any alternative way

Tags: c#, automation, user32

I recently tried those 2 functions:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(int hwndParent,int hwndChildAfter,String lpszClass, String lpszWindow);
```

..so far I received only `IntPtr`s, I know(at least I think) that this returned `int` is the process ID of the Window, now I want to get window's control text and click on button, how to do that?
I can't find anything around...

Comment: I really find these things tough ... maybe u can check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740379/c-sharp-how-to-use-wm-gettext-getwindowtext-api or http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext

Comment: Use a UI automation library if you don't want to learn the winapi.  Project White is pretty popular, so is the .NET System.Windows.Automation namespace.