# Find out if the clipboard content comes from Internet Explorer

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, clipboard, internet-explorer-11

I want to be able to paste clipboard contents with functional hyperlinks to my Winform controls. In order for this to work I tried to check if the Clipboard contains HTML and no RTF and then I could parse the HTML content accordingly. Unfortunately the Internet Explorer generates RTF and HTML in the clipboard content and that way I can't really tell that the content is comming from a browser. Microsoft word for example does the same thing and the only way I found so far to differenciate office products from IE is to check for the namespace xmlns:o"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" in the HTML content of the clipboard. I can't simply use HTML in all cases, because I prefer the RTF or simply the unicode content from other sources than browsers.

Is there a way to determine that the clipboard content comes from a specific application? In my case from IE? So far I only used Clipboard.Contains(TextDataFormat.HTML) and Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats() but I can't find anything else.

Comment: What if the clipboard comes from an IE-powered program? Or some program that choose to generate some other HTML content that you could not understand? Better describe the error to the user.

Comment: Note that checking for content within the data (i.e. the schema of the XML) effectively triggers a "paste" operation, and will have unintended consequences, such as triggering delayed rendering, and causing network traffic if the copy/paste is done over the network with RemDesk or whatever.  Things to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use P/Invoke class to get the calling applications window title using http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowText.html. For IE the title is the name of the page and suffixed with  - Microsoft Internet Explorer, default title for this IE.

This is sample code how to use GetWindowsText
[C# how to use WM_GETTEXT / GetWindowText API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740379/c-sharp-how-to-use-wm-gettext-getwindowtext-api)