# Misleading parameter type in SendMessage (... IntPtr wParam ...)

Tags: c#, c++, interop

While working on issue described in [***What's wrong with this unmanaged code in C#?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759645/whats-wrong-with-this-unmanaged-code-in-c/43760379#43760379) I have stumbled upon parameter ***wParam*** and its type ***IntPtr*** for ***SendMessage*** function.

Code for original function is something like

```
var length = (int)SendMessage(hWnd, WindowMessage.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
var buff = new char[length + 1];
var iptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buff.Length * sizeof(char));
SendMessage(hWnd, WindowMessage.WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)(length + 1), iptr);
Marshal.Copy(iptr, buff, 0, length + 1);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(iptr);
```

I did not like part with allocation and Copy so I have tried to replace it with

```
var length = 1 + (int)SendMessage(hWnd, WindowMessage.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
var buffer = new char[length];
var bufferHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var lengthHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(length, GCHandleType.Pinned);
SendMessage(hWnd, WindowMessage.WM_GETTEXT, lengthHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bufferHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
bufferHandle.Free();
lengthHandle.Free();
```

as it turned out, this will not work because parameter **wParam** is not pointer (which can be concluded from its **IntPtr** type).

Specific description for **WM_GETTEXT** message can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632627.aspx) (thank you SO community for pointing this) and this leads us to following code

```
var length = 1 + (int)SendMessage(hWnd, WindowMessage.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
var buffer = new char[length];
var bufferHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
SendMessage(hWnd, WindowMessage.WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)length, bufferHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
bufferHandle.Free();
```

***Is there a library, or collection of signatures for SendMessage function which is specialized or narrowed for specific messages?***

Do not get me wrong, PInvoke already did ton of work by making this function available to managed world and I appreciate that, however multi-purpose nature of single method makes it more difficult to use.

Comment: Also don't forget that there are two `SendMessage` functions: `SendMessageA` and `SendMessageW`. And in C / C++ code `SendMessage` is typically a macro expanding into one of them depending on `UNICODE` macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy them from the [PInvoke page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage), but note that often I have to modify the PInvoke definitions (they are often 32 bits oriented, so they often suppose that `sizeof(IntPtr) == sizeof(int)`, something very wrong!, or they use the "obsolete" ANSI API, but nowadays the Unicode API should always be used... To give examples, in the linked page, the `SendMessage` with the `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lParam` is using the ANSI API, while the the one with `Int32 wParam` will break on 64 bits)

Your code can be changed to:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

var length = (int)SendMessage(hWnd, WindowMessage.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
var sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
SendMessage(hWnd, WindowMessage.WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);
string str = sb.ToString();
```

using the fact that the pinvoke subsystem "supports" `StringBuilder` for marshaling strings.

Comment: provided sample is closer to specific signature need for this scenario, thank you. I guess part with **wParam** and **IntPtr** will have to remain as such due to marshaling.  
  
In cases when more strict signature is needed then it will be more convenient to I will go with a wrapper function.